# PerformSegue proper call

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

new to Xamarin / MonoTouch

I have a Universal storyboard App (ipad and iphone)
I use storyboards

So I have linked a segue from the MainViewController
to a secondaryViewController (educateViewController).

I do not use nor do I want to use a navigation controller (I'm able to do this in native iOS)

I'm struggling with PerformSegue call which results in

> System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed
>   object of type MyTestApp.educateViewController (0x9827E50) that has
>   been GC'ed ---> System.Exception: No constructor found for
>   MyTestApp.educateViewController::.ctor(System.IntPtr)

I have
private educateViewController educateScreen;

and inside ViewDidLoad()
educateScreen = new educateViewController();

```
partial void educate (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {
            solveIt(sender);

            if (valid) {
                if (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone) {
                    this.PerformSegue("educate", this);  <<<< error occurs here
                } else if (UserInterfaceIdiomIsiPad) {
                    this.Instructor.Hidden = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Segue should only be called if it is on the iPhone

All help welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the EducateViewController implements the following constructor:

```
public EducateViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
}
```

That should allow the view controller to be instantiated from the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**To Perform Segue:**

```
this.PerformSegue("segueIdentifier here", this);
```

**On Target class, Add:**

```
protected MyCustomController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }
```

Note: Please change 'MyCustomController' as your target controller name.